# Use lisp or ironscheme in C# or web?

Tags: model-view-controller, ironscheme

Hi i know that can use ironscheme in c#(visual studio) and i donlowd ironscheme from http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/ on my visual studio 2012 but i dont know how i can use with ironscheme in visual studio .for example i get this sample from http://einarwh.wordpress.com/tag/asp-net-mvc/
that writed with lisp in visual studio but i cant use from this code .
How i should new a project in visual studio for lisp and c# together ?
i know all of function and .... lisp & ironscheme but i cant use that in visual studio with c# !

Comment: Hi, there is a small sample MVC framework written in Scheme included in the IronScheme source package. Demo can be seen @ http://ironscheme.net/blog (src: https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme/tree/master/IronScheme/IronScheme.Web)

Comment: Ho i can download your sample ? https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme/tree/master/IronScheme/IronScheme.Web

Comment: Just download the source from codeplex: https://ironscheme.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for IronScheme is located here:  http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/documentation

If you go about halfway down that page, you will find two subtopics called **"Using .NET from IronScheme"** and **"Using IronScheme from .NET"**.  There, you will find an Eval function which you can use from C#, and some Scheme methods for interacting with the .NET framework.

Example (from [Playing with IronScheme](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33050/Playing-with-IronScheme)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Robert Harvey♦ when i save HelloWorld.ss how i use this in visual studio ? (Save the file, and from the command line...) i should use command line visual studio ?